# Pandas column renaming based on metadata dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

**Problem:** I want to rename column names of a dataframe (`data`) based on a metadata dataframe (`metdata`). Any idea how to do that?

**Expected outcome:**

```
data = pd.DataFrame({"Col 1": [1, 4, 2], "Col X": [3, -1, 2], "Col K": [9, 1, 45]})
```

**Example:**

```
import pandas as pd

metadata = pd.DataFrame({"col_identifier": [12, 45, 9], "col_name": ["Col 1", "Col X", "Col K"]})
data = pd.DataFrame({12: [1, 4, 2], 45: [3, -1, 2], 9: [9, 1, 45]})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `rename` by `Series` created from `metadata` by [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) and selecting column `col_identifier`:

```
data = data.rename(columns=metadata.set_index('col_name')['col_identifier'])
```

Or use dictionary created with `zip`:

```
data = data.rename(columns=dict(zip(metadata['col_name'], metadata['col_identifier'])))
```

---

```
print (data)
   12  45  9 
0   1   3   9
1   4  -1   1
2   2   2  45
```